# How to achieve unique access token from Azure AD for millions of clients with OAuth2

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, token, unique

I am using Azure AD for OAuth2 implementation for my project.
This is a telecom Project where millions of clients/subscribers are connected to our server.

> The idea is to implement OAuth2 with Azure AD as Auth Server and create a
> **single** Project/APP registration for all the clients/subscribers
> belonging to a single operator/company (e.g. Vodafone) in Azure AD
> and generate "Access tokens" so that the clients can use theses token to fetch the
> resource server.

```
However the access tokens generated by Azure AD is the "same for all the clients" which is not acceptable to our requirements. This will be a serious violation of data
```

> The expectation is to ensure **Azure AD generates unique access token
> for each client**. Please inform how to achieve this.

Comment: In that case you would need to acquire a token _on behalf of the user_ using e.g. authorization code flow. It means the user must sign in through the AAD login form. Is that doable for you?

Comment: @juunas Do you mean, we must have to perform APP registration for each and every client so that Azure AD(which acts as  Auth Server) shall respond with a unique token ? For 1 million clients, we must create 1 Million APP registrations??? Instead of doing that, is there any option in Azure AD, where we create a single APP registration and under this APP, we can have 1 million records and each record has its unique values? When any client sends a request, Azure AD can only respond the record(and its values e.g. claim) in the access token ?

Comment: No. You only need one app registration. The access token is unique if the app logs in the user. The token will contain both the app info and the user info.

Comment: How does Azure AD identify different clients inside the same APP ? If I want to configure "optional claim" and assign unique values for each client so that I can get these unique values from access token, can I get it ? Atleast I dont find any ways from the below link on how to configure unique tokens: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-register-app#register-an-application

Comment: Yeah you can't configure unique tokens per user, that's a per app configuration. But you can set an extension property on each user and add that to the token, giving you a different value per user.